# get_posts with multiple categories

Tags: wp-query, categories, get-posts

If I do a get_posts() with category set to 1,2 I will get all posts in category 1 OR 2. 
If i want all posts whit both categories, that is 1 AND 2, how do I make that request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As documented in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) you could use the following

`$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );` //post has to be in category with ID 2 AND 6

Answer (score 3):

The [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters) says:

> **Note:** The category parameter needs to be the ID of the category, and not the category name.
>
> **Note:** The category parameter can be a comma separated list of categories, as the `get_posts()` function passes the 'category' parameter directly into `WP_Query` as `'cat'`.

So it'd be same as `WP_Query()`'s [Category parameter - `cat`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

Comment: Wow, i took for granted that this would give the same result. My bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the WP_QUERY class to search for the posts in some specific categories, here is an example:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
```

Here is a [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Standard_Loop) to the documentation where they explain how to use the results to build a loop and display the posts in the results.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way that just involves the `get_posts()` function.

```
<?php $args1 = array( 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => array(2,3,25,30));
            $myposts1 = get_posts( $args1 );
            foreach ( $myposts1 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <div class="each-post col-lg-aynk col-md-aynk col-sm-aynk col-xs-aynk">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="news-story-img">
                        <?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( get_permalink() ); ?>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>

            <?php endforeach; 
            wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Please explain **why** this helps.

Comment: I can't vote to delete, but the code doesn't even match the comment regarding `get_posts()`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use `category__and` with `get_posts()` directly:

```
$posts = get_posts(array( 'category__and' => array(1,2) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **category_name** as search parameter, you can use `WP_Query( array("category_name" => "cat_1+cat_2+...+cat_n") )`, where `cat_1, cat_2, ... , cat_n` are **all** the categories that the post must have to be returned from the query

Documentation here [Codex Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)